# Rhino reports missing : after property id

Tags: java, javascript, macos, mozilla, rhino

I'm using Rhino 1.7 R4 with envjs 1.2 on Mac OSX with JDK 1.6.0_33

If I run:

```
java -jar rhino-1.7R4.jar -opt -1
```

And then:

```
load('env.rhino-1.2.js')
```

Then the script is loaded successfully.

When I load the same JS script from Java via RhinoTest.java:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ContextAction;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Script;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.ShellContextFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RhinoTest {
    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RhinoTest.class);
    static private Scriptable SCRIPTABLE;
    static private List<Script> scripts;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShellContextFactory cxFactory = Main.shellContextFactory;

        cxFactory.call(new ContextAction() {
            @Override
            public Object run(Context cx) {
                final Initiator initiator = new Initiator(cx).init();

                LOGGER.trace("Run script");
                try {
                    return initiator.execute();
                } finally {
                }
            }

            class Initiator {
                Initiator(Context context) {
                    this.cx = context;
                }

                Initiator init() {
                    if (SCRIPTABLE == null)
                        createScriptable();
                    initContext();
                    return this;
                }

                Object execute() {
                    return null;
                }

                void createScriptable() {

                    LOGGER.trace("init standard objects");
                    SCRIPTABLE = cx.initStandardObjects();

                    LOGGER.trace("set optimization level to -1");
                    cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);// bypass the 64k limit // interpretive mode
                    attachJs("env.rhino-1.2.js");


                    LOGGER.trace("set optimization level to 9");
                    cx.setOptimizationLevel(9);

                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                private void attachJs(String jsFileName) {
                    InputStream in = null;
                    InputStreamReader reader = null;
                    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) LOGGER.debug("loading " + jsFileName);
                    try {
                        in = RhinoTest.class.getResourceAsStream(jsFileName);
                        if (in == null)
                            throw new RuntimeException("cannot find js file : " + jsFileName);

                        reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                        if (scripts == null)
                            scripts = new ArrayList<Script>();
                        scripts.add(cx.compileReader(SCRIPTABLE, reader, jsFileName, 1, null));

                        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) LOGGER.debug("loaded " + jsFileName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("cannot load js file : " + jsFileName, e);
                    } finally {
                        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
                        IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
                    }
                }

                void initContext() {
                    LOGGER.trace("set optimization level to -1");
                    cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);// bypass the 64k limit // interpretive mode

                    for (Script s : scripts) {
                        s.exec(cx, SCRIPTABLE);
                    }

                }

                private final Context cx;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing : after property id (env.rhino-1.2.js#2121)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mustMatchToken(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.argumentList(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExprTail(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parseFunctionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.function(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Unknown Source)
at RhinoTest$1$Initiator.attachJs(RhinoTest.java:85)
at RhinoTest$1$Initiator.createScriptable(RhinoTest.java:63)
at RhinoTest$1$Initiator.init(RhinoTest.java:44)
at RhinoTest$1.run(RhinoTest.java:28)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Unknown Source)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(Unknown Source)
at RhinoTest.main(RhinoTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Please help

Comment: I found that the #2121 refers to the line in the JAvascript that threw the error. That line is:

    get xml() {

Comment: This error quite clearly indicates a Rhino version that doesn't support getters and setters, this support is not configurable. Are you sure that you are using Rhino 1.7 R4 and that you don't have some older version (before 1.6 R6) around?

Comment: mvn dependency:tree | grep rhino

gives:

[INFO] \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile

So only 1.7R4 is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wladimir,

You were right it was a version thing.

It turns out that the batik libs I imported included another version of rhino.

By excluding batik-js from my project for each batik dependency this issue went away.

Comment: This helps me a lot. But I don't find there is a dependency for batik-js in maven dependencies for batik-dom and so on. How do you know you should export it?

Comment: Aiden, Maybe they changed the dependencies. This is an old question.

Comment: Interesting, after I exclude the batik-js, it does work. I will take a look.